# Is this value object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, domain-driven-design

There a two objects, person and image. Person should have stored id int's inside db to properly render image using src attribute.

Consider following scenario

1. Image is uploaded using web forms (mvc)
2. Person entity is created using web form (mvc) and javascript is used to retrieve selected image(s) id to store inside person image property
3. On the view side these person image property is loaded inside img src attrubute to show image

How would you desing Person object

```
Person.cs
Id int not null
// To do
```

Image.cs

```
Id int not null
ImagePath string not null
AlternateText string
```

Comment: Not enough information to determine. More needs to be known about the domain before an answer can be made. Do people in the application have uniqueness? Do images? Do images make sense without a person? Do people make sense without images?

Comment: why don't use a foreign key on image to bind Person id. it allows you to have a Person class with only id property on one side and an image class with an id that is the Person Id (foreign key)

Comment: Generally speaking, if your object has an `Id` property, no it is not a value object. It is an entity.

Answer (score 2):

```
class PersonViewModel
{
    int Id {get; set;}
    int ImageId {get; set;
}
```

Please note that this is a *view-model*, especially tailored for your mvc presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using EF or something similar, you can design your classes like this.

```
public class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public string AlternateText { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<Image> Images {
        get
        {
            return DbContext.Images.Where(image => image.PersonId == this.Id).ToList();
        }}

}
```